# Can't build again my flutter app for android untile I install new android studio and update my configs [Duplicate class]

Tags: java, android, flutter

My local config : Flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.3, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale     fr-FR)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)

[✓] Network resources  • No issues found!

**When I try to launch my flutter app on android I got this error above.**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM G973F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat found in modules jetified-android-zxingLibrary-0.1.4-PRE-runtime (com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.4-PRE) and jetified-core-3.3.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.zxing.Binarizer found in modules jetified-android-zxingLibrary-0.1.4-PRE-runtime (com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.4-PRE) and jetified-core-3.3.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Version found in modules jetified-android-zxingLibrary-0.1.4-PRE-runtime (com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.4-PRE) and jetified-core-3.3.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Version$ECB found in modules jetified-android-zxingLibrary-0.1.4-PRE-runtime (com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.4-PRE) and jetified-core-3.3.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.decoder.Version$ECBlocks found in modules jetified-android-zxingLibrary-0.1.4-PRE-runtime (com.github.leyan95:android-zxingLibrary:0.1.4-PRE) and jetified-core-3.3.0 (com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 59s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Why I Tried in order to resolve :**

- Ideleted my cashes
- I updated dependences & repaired  cashes
- I deleted .gradle
  cd ~
  rm -rf .gradle

Comment: can you share your gradle files?

Comment: android/build.gradle  :  https://gist.github.com/toure5013/7ba7dfb6ecb1810a18f780d826672543

/android/app/build.gradle  :  https://gist.github.com/toure5013/d42abf6ddf08f73f807fb2ec12eff872





android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties : 


#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip